# Individual nodejs instances per user

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine

I've been searching for a way to set up a new separate nodejs instance for each new user to be able to use.

My plan is to use google app engine and I've read about clusters but i don't think that's the correct way to go.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Why would every user need their own server instance?  Usually a single server can serve the needs of thousands of users.

Comment: The bot would be ticking for new data that's designated to the user. Wouldn't that tie up the thread?

Comment: io will be mostly asynchronous and will allow other code to run. Unless you are doing huge amounts of processing per request you will likely be able to serve 100's or possibly 1000's of users on a single node thread.

Comment: What kind of code is "ticking for new data"?  Is that just a network request?

Comment: Yeah it's a network request that would probably run for quite sometime.

Comment: I would think that would tie up the thread would it not? The script would run automatically but i have recursive calls that may run for long periods of time.

Comment: Network requests are asynchronous in node.js.  They do NOT tie up the Javascript thread.  We can't really help you further without seeing your actual code.  You appear to be operating under several wrong assumptions about what does and doesn't tie up the Javascript thread.  The ONLY way we can help you further is if you show us your actual code and we can then advise what you do an don't need to fix/change.